# Making a faster executing sort function

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a data set thats over 1000 items and the issue Im having is the amount of time it takes for the table to be sorted. Ive built a few tables recently and the sort function Ive been using has always been sufficient until now I am assuming its the size data thats causing it to return so slow? I dont have the option of doing this on the backend. Im not sure how to update the loading state in my function properly so the time between when the sort is clicked and the and sorted data is returned is at least showing loading.

this is my sort function and Im wondering if there is any way to optimize it:

```
const sortTable = (field, order) => {
    let sorted = formItems?.sort((a, b) => {
        setLoading(true)
        if (order === "asc") {
            return a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1;
        } else {
            return a[field] < b[field] ? 1 : -1;
        }
    })
    setLoading(false)
    setFormItems(sorted)
}
```

Comment: In your current implementation `setLoading(true)` is called at least 1000 times, but I'm not sure if it is a performance issue. Sorting is slow by default. You can reduce the data that is sorted or move this logic to the backend.

Comment: maybe you do not use zero for equal items ...?

Comment: @NinaScholz yes, this is not a valid sort comparator function if the list of items may contain equal values.

Comment: Also the ascending/descending decision should be made *outside* the sorting process, with appropriate comparators passed in.

Comment: The data will not contain equal values.Each item will be unique. @NinaScholz

Comment: optimisation questions should be asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Unrelated but `formItems` will already be sorted before you call `setFormItems(sorted)`, so you may reconsider this call -- but it depends on what you do there.

Comment: Could you edit your question and provide an example that can be run, and that shows the problem with the performance? Maybe include a Stack Snippet (use the toolbar).

Comment: @Pointy could you explain what you mean by this? From what I understand I am passing in ascending/descending into my handleSort function as `order` and inside the function i am determining the sorting order based on that value. Are you saying I should have two different functions for each?

Comment: If you make the ordering decision *outside* the `.sort()`, and pass in either an ascending function or a descending function, then you won't have to make that decision thousands of times during the sort process.

Comment: In case only k entries are shown to the user in the end it might make sense to use a top-k sort instead.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJwEwA5gOkM

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
const sortTable = (field, order) => {
  // run just once
  setLoading(true);

  // avoid batching (react < 18)
  setTimeout(() => {
    // change value based on previous state
    setFormItems((prev) => {
      if (!prev) return prev; // avoid optional chaining (subjective)
      const formItemsCopy = [...prev]; // stay immutable

      // simplify
      const x = order === 'asc' ? 1 : -1;
      formItemsCopy.sort((a, b) => {
        return (a[field] - b[field]) * x;
      });

      return formItemsCopy;
    });

    setLoading(false);
  }, 0);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your condition and setLoading funtion outside of sort funtion

```
const sortTable = (field, order) => {
   setLoading(true)
   Var sorted = []
   if (order === "asc") {
     sorted = formItems?.sort((a, b) => a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1)
    } else {
      sorted = formItems?.sort((a, b) =>  a[field] < b[field] ? 1 : -1)
    }
    setLoading(false)
    setFormItems(sorted)
}
```

Comment: This won't show any loading indicator though